# LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types (unique new post)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, expression-trees

**Preface**

I counted probably 20 questions pertaining to this particular error, but I did not find that any of them apply.  I am doing something different in that I am creating my expressions programatically rather than by literal lambda syntax.  I suspect that this may be unearthing other complications.

The code below uses some of my helpers as well as my own UnitOfWork class.  For brevity, I will not drag all of that here, but will provide any additional code upon request.

**The question**

I am trying to perform `IQueryable` operations on a `SelectMany`.  It works when I write out the expressions literally.  However, because I need to be able to build all of this dynamically, I don't have the option of literal expressions.

See code below for comments.

```
Unable to cast the type 'IQueryable`1[[SystemAssociateModel]]' to type 'IEnumerable`1[[SystemAssociateModel]]'.
LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

`☺`

```
public static void SelectManyTest()
{
    int id = 14690;

    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SystemEntitlement));

    var projector = ExpressionHelpers.GetLambda<SystemAssociate, SystemAssociateModel>(x => new SystemAssociateModel
    {
        role = x.Role.Name,
        id = x.Associate.Id,
        order = x.Order
    });

    var memberPath = ExpressionHelpers.GetLambda<SystemEntitlement, ICollection<SystemAssociate>>(
        x => x.System.Associates).Body.AsMemberExpression().ReplaceInstance(p);

    //These two calls equate to this:  x.System.Associates.AsQueryable().Select(projector)
    var call_asQueryable = Expression.Call(ExpressionHelpers.GetMethodInfo(() => Queryable.AsQueryable<SystemAssociate>(null)), memberPath);
    Expression call_select = Expression.Call(ExpressionHelpers.GetMethodInfo(
        () => Queryable.Select(default(IQueryable<SystemAssociate>), default(Expression<Func<SystemAssociate, SystemAssociateModel>>))),
        call_asQueryable, projector);

    //I use this in an attempt to cast my `Select` into `IEnumerable` for `SelectMany`.  This
    //is most likely where the issue is occurring.  It makes sense that only specific types of
    //casts would be supported within an expression.
    //call_select = Expression.Convert(call_select, typeof(IEnumerable<SystemAssociateModel>));

    //I have to use the uncommented line since that's the only one suitable for `.SelectMany`.
    //This is the reason for the cast above, to convert `Select`'s `IQueryable` into an
    //`IEnumerable` for `SelectMany`.  If I don't use the explicit cast, it will attempt an
    //implicit cast and still fail.
    //var selector = (Expression<Func<SystemEntitlement, IQueryable<SystemAssociateModel>>>)Expression.Lambda(call_select, masterp);
    var selector = (Expression<Func<SystemEntitlement, IEnumerable<SystemAssociateModel>>>)Expression.Lambda(call_select, p);

    //This works so long as I write the `.SelectMany` expression literally.  I seems that the compiler is somehow
    //able to handle the implicit cast from `ICollection` to `IEnumerable`.
    var associates1 = UnitOfWork.UseWith(work => work.GetRepo<SystemEntitlement>().AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .SelectMany(x => x.System.Associates.AsQueryable().Select(projector))
    .Where(x => x.order == 1)
    .ToArray());

    //This throws the error in question.
    var associates2 = UnitOfWork.UseWith(work => work.GetRepo<SystemEntitlement>().AsQueryable()
    .Where(pred)
    .SelectMany(selector)
    .Where(x => x.order == 1)
    .ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF does not support such casts, so no `Expression.Convert` should be used.

The actual problem is that `Expression.Lambda(call_select, p)` returns `Expression<Func<T, IQueryable<R>>>` which you are trying to cast to `Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<R>>>`. But `Expression` as any C# *class* does not support variance, hence the cast expectedly fails.

The solution is to use `Expression.Lambda` method overloads which allow you to specify the desired result type. In your sample, it could be like this:

```
var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<SystemEntitlement, IEnumerable<SystemAssociateModel>>>(
    call_select, p);
```

Once you do that, the problem will be solved.

As a side note - when you build expressions dynamically, there is no need of applying `AsQueryable` on collection navigation properties - it's used to trick the C# compiler to allow using `Expression<Func<...>>` variable inside what you call literal expressions in methods that expect `Func<...>`. When you emit `Expression.Call` by hand, you could simply call the corresponding `Enumerable` method:

```
var call_select = Expression.Call(ExpressionHelpers.GetMethodInfo(
    () => Enumerable.Select(default(IEnumerable<SystemAssociate>), default(Func<SystemAssociate, SystemAssociateModel>))),
    memberPath, projector);
```

Here I'm guessing the expected arguments of your `ExpressionHelpers.GetMethodInfo`. I personally "call" generic methods like this:

```
var call_select = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new[] { typeof(SystemAssociate), typeof(SystemAssociateModel) },
    memberPath, projector);
```

Of course `AsQueryable` doesn't hurt in EF6, but is redundant and is not supported in EF Core.

Comment: As usual with expressions, Ivan Stoev for the win.  Using that lambda overload did the trick.  As for not calling AsQueryable, I originally just called Select, but it tells me I can't call Select on my ICollection navigation property, hence why I convert it to IQueryable in this way.